# Which http method does ng-include uses to load url provided to it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

It may seem to be very naive question, but I have googled out, but couldn't find an appropriate answer. My Question is which http method does ng-include uses to load html from url provided as value of src attribute ? Moreover, is it possible to specify which http method to use to include a resource with ng-include ?

Answer (score 2):

angular uses `XMLHTTpRequest` to get the file. it creates an instance of it and forward configuration for further modification.

This method is called by angular to get an instance of `XMLHTTpRequest`

```
   function createXhr() {
        return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    }


$templateRequest(src, true).then(function(response) {
       if (thisChangeId !== changeCounter) return;
       var newScope = scope.$new();
       ctrl.template = response;
       var clone = $transclude(newScope, function(clone) {
       cleanupLastIncludeContent();
       $animate.enter(clone, null, $element).then(afterAnimation);
 });
```

`$templateRequest` is done through `$TemplateRequestProvider`

it makes a call to $http service. line #17521

```
return $http.get(tpl, httpOptions)
        ['finally'](function() {
          handleRequestFn.totalPendingRequests--;
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          $templateCache.put(tpl, response.data);
          return response.data;
        }, handleError);
```

which then process request to get the file.

can refer to line #10407 in `angular.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

It uses GET method, you can monitor requests using a developer tools with network features.

No, you can't change http method.